# To keep sb informed

Tags: tense, past-participles

In the sentence:

> Newspapers keep us informed about world news as well as provid**ing**
>   interesting reading material.

Why do they use **ing**-verb here? I expected past participle should have been used instead.

> They keep us informed ... as well as provided ...

Why is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct interpretation of the sentence is:

- Newspapers keep us informed about worlds news
- Newspapers are providing interesting reading material

The problem occurs because the word "are" has been omitted in the original sentence. This is common, but not strictly correct (at least in my opinion).

Your suggested sentence "Newspapers keep us informed about world news as well as provided with interesting reading material" is grammatically correct, but it is unlikely that anyone would phrase it is this manner.

Comment: "Newspapers keep us informed" cannot accept "are" anywhere. What I think you mean is that in this case it would be better to rephrase as "Newspapers **are keeping us informed…".